# How to get PlaceID from name, or lat, long in Android?

Tags: android, google-geocoder

This my code:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(text, 10);
    test.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < addresses.size(); i++) {
        Address address = addresses.get(i);
        for (int j=0;j<address.getMaxAddressLineIndex();j++) {
            test.add(address.getAddressLine(j) + ", " + address.getCountryName());
//                address.getLatitude();
//                address.getLatitude();
            }
        }
```

But I can't find something like address.getPlaceID().

Maybe I use another API get PlaceID from name, or lat, long from above code. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look at this [docs](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id).
You will get the lat,long,name for the `Address`
and then call this below google api

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=cruise&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

You will get a response like this

```
{
  "html_attributions" : [],
  "results" : [
    {
      "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
          "lat" : -33.870775,
          "lng" : 151.199025
        }
      },
      ...
      "place_id" : "ChIJrTLr-GyuEmsRBfy61i59si0",
      ...
    }
  ],
  "status" : "OK"
}
```

For there you will get the place-id.

> Note: Please enable the GeoLocation Api from [Google Developer Console](https://console.cloud.google.com) otherwise it return the error msg :This API project is not authorized to use this API.

Comment: Their terms of service restrict this from being used in a client application (like in an android app).  You'll need to run this on the server and cache it.

Comment: this is the web api, not the android one, OP wants to do this with the official android sdk

Comment: @JohnLeehey so how do we get place info from a lat/lng on the client device?

Comment: CC: @ÁbrahámEndre

Comment: @KhalilKhalaf you'll need to register for a billing account with google.  After that, `YOUR_API_KEY` will be replaced with the one given to you for that google account, and you will be billed according to the volume of requests you make.

Comment: @JohnLeehey I have API KEY, and I use it for distances matrix and duration between addresses. But I was replying to your first comment that it is not a client application and will need to run this on the server. Do I still have to register a billing account?

Comment: As noted by other people, this is not an acceptable answer as this web service API is not intended to be used by clients.

Answer (score 3):

You also can use **direct** search instead of **nearbysearch**
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Look at [Getting Started with Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start)

Comment: This is geocode api not place api so it will not contain place id in response

Comment: This does not work, it says I am not authorized? [**See Here**](https://s1.postimg.org/ix6hxz8r3/Screen_Shot_2017-08-01_at_2.23.27_PM.png)

Answer (score 1):

Both of the proposed ways cost money and I think peoples should mention it. We have the -$200 from the Google, but its all depends from how much users you have and how frequent you need to use the geocode. 60k requests per month to the geocoder - easy $300 only for to use the geocode https API :

Nov 1 – 30, 2018
Geocoding API Geocoding: 6073 Counts - $30.38

Dont filter what you need in the responses, like we have in the requests from other posts? Expect way more:

Nov 1 – 30, 2018
Places API Places Details: 2389 Counts $40.61

Nov 1 – 30, 2018
Places API Contact Data: 2385 Counts $7.17

Nov 1 – 30, 2018
Places API Atmosphere Data: 2385 Counts $11.95

Answer (score 0):

I do recommend to use get the Place Id like this. It would be better than call the API directly.
I stumble for this issue all day. so I hope that it would be help. who're finding  the way out to get place ID from your current location.
for android

> Kotlin

```kotlin
val mPlaceDetectionClient = Places.getPlaceDetectionClient(this.context!!)  
val placeResult =  mPlaceDetectionClient.getCurrentPlace(null) 
placeResult.addOnCompleteListener(object : OnCompleteListener<PlaceLikelihoodBufferResponse>{
    override fun onComplete(p0: Task<PlaceLikelihoodBufferResponse>) {
        val likelyPlaces = p0.result
        if(likelyPlaces.any()){
            // get the place ID from code below
            placeId = likelyPlaces[0].place.id  }
    }

})
```

or if who are implementing or developing on another language such a **java**. you can implement your code according to a reference below.

> **java**

https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/googleapi-migration