# How do I get place id using latitude and longitude?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-api

I want to get place id using lat and lng.
There is some code:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            String title = marker.getTitle();
            LatLng position = marker.getPosition();
            marker.showInfoWindow();
            double lat;
            double lng;
            lat = marker.getPosition().latitude;
            lng = marker.getPosition().longitude;

            return true;
        }
    });
```

When I click on marker I want to get place id. How may I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283484/how-to-get-placeid-from-name-or-lat-long-in-android

Comment: Where and how I have to request this url "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=cruise&key=YOUR_API_KEY" ?

Answer (score -1):

`getPlace()`

Return Value:  MarkerPlace

might help you.