# How to get place or placeid by latLng in android using google places api?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

How to get place or placeid by latLng in android using google places api ?
I want to get place or placeid when i get latLng

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34283813/4056108)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get PlaceID from name, or lat, long in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283484/how-to-get-placeid-from-name-or-lat-long-in-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**you can use this Google Maps API**

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=23.00,72.57&sensor=true
```

Comment: This does not work, it says I am not authorized? [**See Here**](https://s1.postimg.org/ix6hxz8r3/Screen_Shot_2017-08-01_at_2.23.27_PM.png)

Comment: Do you still use it? I think that now its not so good way, because it can cost a lot of money even on apps with several thousands users. Of course, in case you use it frequently.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented in my application using this way

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=21.1702401,72.8310607&key=YOUR_API_KEY

u will get Response like this which contains place_id.

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
           //It contains postal code and details
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "22 Demart, Surat, India,
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 21.1702401,
               "lng" : 72.8310607
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 21.1702401,
                  "lng" : 72.8310607
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 21.1702401,
                  "lng" : 72.8310607
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJd8BlQ2BZwokRAFUEcm_qrcA",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      },

   ... Additional results truncated in this example[] ...

   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

you can refer this link also

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start

Hope this will help u..u can ask if any question

Comment: This does not work, it says I am not authorized? [**See Here**](https://s1.postimg.org/ix6hxz8r3/Screen_Shot_2017-08-01_at_2.23.27_PM.png)

Comment: Generate SHA key and bind it with api key u have to use goole place api key

Answer (score 0):

Both of the proposed ways - cost money and I think peoples should mention it. Yes, we have the -$200 from the Google, but its all depends from how much users you have and how frequent you need to use the geocoder. 60k requests per month to the geocoder - easy $300 only for to use the geocoder :

Nov 1 – 30, 2018
Geocoding API Geocoding: 6073 Counts - $30.38

Dont filter what you need in the responses, like we have in the requests from other posts? Expect way more:

Nov 1 – 30, 2018
Places API Places Details: 2389 Counts $40.61

Nov 1 – 30, 2018
Places API Contact Data: 2385 Counts $7.17

Nov 1 – 30, 2018
Places API Atmosphere Data: 2385 Counts $11.95