# Flutter: how to get all the information about a marked point on the map ( name, review, photo, ...)

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-places-api

[image]

I'm trying to find a way to get all information about a marked point by click that point on the Map (red circle on the picture).
According to what i have read
firstly. I'm using `placemarkFromCoordinates()` function from `geocoding` package. and the parameter is the value when user onTap on map

Its return looks like this:

```
[     
      Name: Vincom Centre Metropolis,
      Street: Kim Ma,
      ISO Country Code: VN,
      Country: Vietnam,
      Postal code: ,
      Administrative area: Ha Noi,
      Subadministrative area: Ba Dinh,
      Locality: Hanoi,
      Sublocality: Ngoc Khanh,
      Thoroughfare: Kim Ma,
      Subthoroughfare: 
]
```

After getting the **name of the place**, i will using `place api` to search marker by name

it works well with famous places but with other places. it's only return address, not name of mark. Therefore, it is not possible to get the correct information when pressing

```
[      
      Name: 808A Lang,
      Street: 808A Lang,
      ISO Country Code: VN,
      Country: Vietnam,
      Postal code: ,
      Administrative area: Ha Noi,
      Subadministrative area: Dong Da,
      Locality: Hanoi,
      Sublocality: Lang Thuong,
      Thoroughfare: Lang,
      Subthoroughfare: 808A
]
```

i want to do like google map. When clicking on the marked points, the information of that point will be displayed (including name, review, photo)

i'm also read about `place API` of google map, but `detail_place API` require `place_id` after searching.

Is there any way to get it via `LatLng`?

Comment: check here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50618135/how-to-get-place-id-using-coordinates-lat-lon-in-android